# Converting xls to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a xls 
file. Which have following data.

[image]

Now I want to get the values inserted into a datatable dt1. I just want a simple procedure with plain c#. no api/ dll. What i have tried is given below:

```
string strfilename = "";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            strfilename = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

        string[] csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strfilename); ;

        string[] fields = null;
        foreach (string csvRow in csvRows)
        {
            fields = csvRow.Split(',');
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = fields;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Here my csvRow should find 7 rows. but it get 131 rows. and they are unreadable for me. some kind of symbolic.

Comment: What is wrong with your code / why are your results incorrect?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I am editing and attaching the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a DataTable but you haven't defined any columns in it (AKA Schema).
You need to have at least the same amount of columns as many fields (comma separated) are present in your CSV file

Add this before entering the reading loop

```
 string[] csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strfilename); 
 for(int x = 0; i < csvRows.Length; x++)
     dt.Columns.Add("Col" + x.ToString());
```

Now your ItemArray has the same number of 'columns' of your csv.

Comment: Here you can see, there is only one column used. Column A. When i use your code that creates 30 column frm the csv file.

and one thing else. it is not a csvfile. it's a xls file. is it creating any difference?

Comment: First Line (1)--> colA,colB
2nd Line (2)--> A,B
3rd Line (3)--> c,d
...................
...................

Comment: If this is an Excel files (xls) then there is a big difference from CSV files. XLS are binary files and cannot be read in a meaningful way with File.ReadAllLines. You should export the XLS file in CSV format (Save as...)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example it may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429712/Convert-CSV-File-to-data-table